# php style function check in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I don't recollect exactly what its called but php checks and exists as soon as it finds one false value in a function, like so :

```
// php
if(isset(a["hi"]) && isset(a["hi"]["hello"])) {

}
```

here if `a["hi"]` is not set, it will not bother to check the next `a["hi"]["hello"]`.

to check something like this in javascript you'd need to nest

```
// js
if(typeof(a["hi"]) != "undefined") {
    if(typeof(a["hi"]["hello"]) != "undefined") {

    }
}
```

Can we do php style lazy checking in javascript? 
(I may not be using the best method to check if an element exists in a multi-dimentional array, if there is a succinct way of doing this, would love to know.)

thanks!

Comment: Is the term you're looking for how the multi-step boolean check is "short-circuited" at the first non-true expression? JavaScript has that as well (although it has different behavior in the case of assignment of a multi-step boolean such as `foo = bar || {}` (but that's not your question)

Comment: @LarryOBrien Thanks, yes, its "short-circuited" and yes, now it seems to work, wasn't constructing the statement correctly in firebug.

Comment: If `a['hi']['hello'] is  `defined` . There's no way, `a['hi']` would be `undefined`. I think you need the second condition only.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `in` to check property existence.

```
if(a && ('hi' in a) && ('hello' in a['hi'])) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use this, it reads much better than typeof.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a.hi === undefined && a.hi.hello === undefined) {
```

if you know that a.hi can never be a falsey value (`null` / `false` / `0`) you can do

```
if(!a.hi && !a.hi.hello) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking the `typeof` a variable for the string `"undefined"` is equivalent to using `===` to check whether the variable is the same data type as the `undefined` keyword. You can therefore reduce the nested if statements to a single statement:

```
if(a.hi !== undefined && a.hi.hello !== undefined) {
  // do something with a.hi.hello
}
```

It's worth noting that the statement above assumes that `a` is not null when the if statement takes place which could cause errors. It also holds true that if you require `a.hi.hello` to be present for the `if` statement to evaluate, then you can use falsy checking for `a` and `a.hi` as they would need to be `object` types for (which are non-falsy):

```
if(!!a && a.hi && a.hi.hello !== undefined) {
  // do something with a.hi.hello
}
```